# How to feed WordPress Blogs into Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress, api, rss

I would like to be able to automatically import my WP blogs into a Facebook page for a client.
I know that there are wp plugins that used to do this, but Facebook now requires ssl connections and these plugins no longer work.  I think that there may be a way of using the Facebook API, (kind of like an rss feed) but I can't find any instructions. Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your own you can create an app and use something like http://jquery.malsup.com/gfeed/ to import your blog in.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress generates an RSS feed of your blog. This you can import into Facebook using, for example, RSS Graffitti.